# Unable to install Windows mobile device center after uninstall on Windows 10 system

Tags: windows-10, windows-mobile-device-center

We are currently developing a project on wince devices.
I'm trying to install WMDC but gives an error.

I tried lots solutions but could not have it reinstalled?

Getting the error: "Windows Mobile Device Center could not be installed because at least one required Windows component is missing."

Comment: Well WMDC is more than 12 years old. Have you read https://junipersys.com/index.php/support/knowledge-base/support-knowledge-base-topics/desktop-connection-activesync-or-windows-mobile-device-center/wmdc-in-windows-10

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Yes already tried those steps. Actually in the first time they worked form me. But last day WMDC started not to launch on docking the device. So i retired the steps. And they did not work this time. So i uninstalled WMDC and now i cannot reinstall it

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? What has changed on the device?

Comment: Windows Mobile Device Center could not be installed because at least one required Windows component is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Missing component is Media player. It must be added from additional features. (Not sure installing media feature pack is required or not.) After added as feature it requires a reboot.
Adding as feature only makes it selectable on the add/remove windows features window.
So i selected and it required a reboot again.

After installing media player I'm able to install "drvupdate-amd64.exe" successfully

Thanks for your time.